# Как вывести числа в отдельный txt файл?

Tags: python

Нужна помощь. Есть программа(пример ниже) хочу что-бы переменная dry_count выводилась в отдельный txt файл после закрытия программы. dry_count отвечает за количество выводящих строк в консоль, их нужно посчитать и вывести в отдельный txt.

```
from colorama import *
import random
import time
import os

adr = ['241', '4325', '4356']

word = ['Ho', 'Ia', 'Choose']

i = 1

dry_count = 0

while i < 10:
    print(Fore.YELLOW + 'Адресс:', random.choice(adr), '|', Fore.YELLOW + 'Бал 0', '|', Fore.YELLOW + 'Слова:', random.choice(word))
    dry_count + 1
    time.sleep(0.05)
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

- Элемент списка

Comment: А в чем проблема? Записать значение в файл? Судя потому, что Вы добрались до цветного вывода в консоль с этим проблем не должно быть вроде.

Comment: Пока у вас dry_count не переменная, а постоянная.

Comment: @Namerek Хочу что-бы после закрытия программы итоговое число в dry_count выводилось в отдельный txt файл. Т.е результат

Comment: `i += 1` в цикл добавьте и почитайте про `open()`.